# AudioQueueOfflineRender questions

Tags: iphone, audio, core-audio

I have a few questions about this after reading the iPhone documentation on it:

1. Does this take the audio being played and save it to a buffer so it can be written to a file?
2. If so does the audio being played have to be played using a playback audio queue or can it be played via a higher level class such as AVAudioPlayer.
3. Can anyone point me in the direction of some sample code or further help than the docs.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes
2. Pretty sure you need to use a/the playback audio queue.
3. [This](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2009/qa1562.html) Apple QA points to a file called aqrender.cpp which implements point 1.